# Custom Menus Links not working in category page

Tags: wordpress, menu, sidebar

Custom Menu Links are not displaying in category page. When i checked the source, it shows me like this.

```
<div class="sidebar-widget">
 <h1 class="widget-title">Popular Categories</h1>
  <div class="menu-cus_menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-cus_menu" class="menu"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The same function i called for my home page. But it is working fine. The following code is in `sidebar.php`

```
<?php
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-hompage-widget-area' ) && is_home() ) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-hompage-widget-area' );
    }
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-category-widget-area' ) && is_category() ) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-category-widget-area' );
    }
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left-widget-area' ) ) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left-widget-area' );
    }
?>
```

Please help me to find out right solution or suggest me to find my mistake.

Comment: you will need to give a bit more to go on. Did you correctly link the menu? On what page is this not working?

Comment: i have displayed custom menus in home page. But it is not working in category pages

Answer (score 0):

As far as i think you have a Category page not a category.php or archive.php file.  is_category() function only works within category.php or archive.php file. Instead of using is_category try use is_page('category').

For more information on is_category() see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category.

Comment: category.php file is there. In that get_sidebar() is called, The problem is custom menu links are not displaying. Instead, custom menu title alone displaying. Please help me.